# Apply function on dataframe counting power of difference between int and series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to add a new column to dataframe with apply function. I need to count distance between X and Y coords in row 0 and all other rows, I have created following logic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'X':[0,0,0,1,1,5,6,7,8],'Y':[0,1,4,2,6,5,6,4,8],'Value':[6,7,4,5,6,5,6,4,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def countDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
        print(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
        #use basic knowledge about triangles - values are in meters
        distance = np.sqrt(np.power(lat1-lat2,2)+np.power(lon1-lon2,2))
        return distance

def recModif(df):
        x = df.loc[0,'X']
        y = df.loc[0,'Y']
        df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda n: countDistance(x,y,df['X'],df['Y']), axis=1)
        #more code will come here

recModif(df)
```

But this always returns error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies`

I thought that as x and y are scalars, using `np.repeat` might help but it didn't, the error was still the same. I saw similar posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667402/apply-function-with-constant-parameter-to-pandas-dataframe), but with multiplication which is simple, how can I achieve subtraction like I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name in `.apply()` was messed up and collides with the outer scope. Avoid that and the code works.

```
df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: countDistance(x,y,row['X'],row['Y']), axis=1)

df
   X  Y  Value       dist
0  0  0      6   0.000000
1  0  1      7   1.000000
2  0  4      4   4.000000
3  1  2      5   2.236068
4  1  6      6   6.082763
5  5  5      5   7.071068
6  6  6      6   8.485281
7  7  4      4   8.062258
8  8  8      8  11.313708
```

Also note that np.power() and np.sqrt() are already vectorized, so .apply itself is redundant for the dataset given:

```
countDistance(x,y,df['X'],df['Y'])

Out[154]: 
0     0.000000
1     1.000000
2     4.000000
3     2.236068
4     6.082763
5     7.071068
6     8.485281
7     8.062258
8    11.313708
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your end goal I suggest changing the function recModif to:

```
def recModif(df):
    x = df.loc[0,'X']
    y = df.loc[0,'Y']
    df['dist'] = countDistance(x,y,df['X'],df['Y'])
    #more code will come here
```

This outputs

```
X   Y   Value   dist
0   0   0   6   0.000000
1   0   1   7   1.000000
2   0   4   4   4.000000
3   1   2   5   2.236068
4   1   6   6   6.082763
5   5   5   5   7.071068
6   6   6   6   8.485281
7   7   4   4   8.062258
8   8   8   8   11.313708
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try this:

```py
## Method-1
df['dist'] = ((df.X - df.X[0])**2 + (df.Y - df.Y[0])**2)**0.5

## Method-2: .apply()
x, y = df.X[0], df.Y[0]
df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: ((row.X - x)**2 + (row.Y - y)**2)**0.5, axis=1)
```

**Output**:

```sh
# print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

|   X |   Y |   Value |     dist |
|----:|----:|--------:|---------:|
|   0 |   0 |       6 |  0       |
|   0 |   1 |       7 |  1       |
|   0 |   4 |       4 |  4       |
|   1 |   2 |       5 |  2.23607 |
|   1 |   6 |       6 |  6.08276 |
|   5 |   5 |       5 |  7.07107 |
|   6 |   6 |       6 |  8.48528 |
|   7 |   4 |       4 |  8.06226 |
|   8 |   8 |       8 | 11.3137  |
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'X': [0,0,0,1,1,5,6,7,8],
    'Y': [0,1,4,2,6,5,6,4,8],
    'Value':[6,7,4,5,6,5,6,4,8]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: @Ruli Please take a look at this. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: this does not count as I need, you omit the subtract here

Comment: @Ruli Updated the solution. Please check now.